# parse array of object that contains JSON elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

## First let me break down the data:

I have an array that contains 3 elements...

Each Element is an object with `name` and `arrayOfJSON` as keys...

Inside `arrayOfJSON` there could be any number of JSON strings as elements...

I need to capture the position where `Alex@gmail` occurs for both the array `mess` and `arrayOfJSON`

Result Should Be:

> position_of_mess = [0,2]
>
> position_of_arrayOfJSON_for_position_of_mess_0 = [0]
>
> position_of_arrayOfJSON_for_position_of_mess_2 = [1]

## What I'm trying at the moment:

For loop through mess, for loop through arrayOfJSON , and JSON.parse() for Alex@gmail.
going to take me a few mins to update.

If y'all think it can be done without a for-loop let me know.

## Update: almost there

```
mess = [{
    "name": "user1",
    "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"Alex@gmail","hobby":"coding"},{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"}]`
  },
  {
    "name": "user2",
    "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"Chris@gmail","hobby":"coding"},{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"}]`
  },
  {
    "name": "user3",
    "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"},{"email":"Alex@gmail","hobby":"coding"}]`
  }
]


console.log(mess)

for (i = 0; i < mess.length; i++) {
  console.log(JSON.parse(mess[i].arrayOfJSON))
  
  for (m = 0; m < (JSON.parse(mess[i].arrayOfJSON)).length; m++) {
    console.log("almost")
    console.log((JSON.parse(mess[i].arrayOfJSON))[m])
  } 
}
```

Comment: Reassign `arrayOfJSON` to the JSON value after parsing.

Comment: Why do you have those backticks in your definition of `mess`?

Comment: @Mister Jojo I disagree with your observation... would you like to clarify how mess does not contain 3 elements, instead of just saying "wrong". If mess does not have 3 elements, why does mess.length === 3 ???

Comment: @GetSet JSFiddle.net would not let me put stringyphy JSON as " " had to use ` `

Comment: If you look at the update, you can see it just a typo, it happens

Answer (score 0):

1. Parse your data

   - You want to be able to access keys inside the inner object "string"
2. Traverse your data

   - While visiting key-value pairs, build a scope thet you can later return

```js
// Adapted from: https://gist.github.com/sphvn/dcdf9d683458f879f593
const traverse = function(o, fn, scope = []) {
  for (let i in o) {
    fn.apply(this, [i, o[i], scope]);
    if (o[i] !== null && typeof o[i] === "object") {
      traverse(o[i], fn, scope.concat(i));
    }
  }
}

const mess = [{
  "name": "user1",
  "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"Alex@gmail","hobby":"coding"},{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"}]`
}, {
  "name": "user2",
  "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"Chris@gmail","hobby":"coding"},{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"}]`
}, {
  "name": "user3",
  "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"},{"email":"Alex@gmail","hobby":"coding"}]`
}];

// Parse...
mess.forEach(item => {
  if (item.arrayOfJSON) {
    item.arrayOfJSON = JSON.parse(item.arrayOfJSON);
  }
});

traverse(mess, (key, value, scope) => {
  if (value === 'Alex@gmail') {
    console.log(
      `Position: mess[${scope.concat(key).map(k => isNaN(k) ? `'${k}'` : k).join('][')}]`
    );
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: I used .map in my answer and I get -1 when Alex@gmail is not in arrayOfJSON, is that consistent ??

Comment: Nevermind: found documentation on indexOf() This method returns -1 if the value to search for never occurs.

Comment: @Jay Yeah, -1 is always the value that gets returned if the item is not present on the array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
mess = [{
    "name": "user1",
    "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"Alex@gmail","hobby":"coding"},{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"}]`
  },
  {
    "name": "user2",
    "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"Chris@gmail","hobby":"coding"},{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"}]`
  },
  {
    "name": "user3",
    "arrayOfJSON": `[{"email":"bob@gmail","hobby":"coocking"},{"email":"Alex@gmail","hobby":"coding"}]`
  }
]


console.log(mess)
holdMessPosition = []

for (i = 0; i < mess.length; i++) {

  var pos = (JSON.parse(mess[i].arrayOfJSON)).map(function(e) {
      return e.email;
    })
    .indexOf("Alex@gmail");
  console.log("user position is " + pos);

  if (pos !== -1) {
    holdMessPosition.push(i)
  }

}

console.log(holdMessPosition)
```